# Lock WiFi settings for the ordinary user with a password

Tags: wi-fi, security, password

I'm looking for a way to make WiFi settings inaccessible to regular users. For example, locks the WiFi settings with a password, so that an ordinary user cannot turn off the WiFi or log in to a different SSID. The device has Android 12.

Is there a way to use the Automate app, Macrodroid app, or another? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restrictions on apps only. This question has been edited to conform to the accepted policy. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.